# PHP: Concatenate array element into string with ',' as the separator

Tags: php

Is there a quick way ( existing method)  Concatenate array element into string with ',' as the separator? Specifically I am looking for a single line of method replacing the following routine:

```
//given ('a','b','c'), it will return 'a,b,c'
private static function ConstructArrayConcantenate($groupViewID)
{
    $groupIDStr='';
    foreach ($groupViewID as $key=>$value) {
        $groupIDStr=$groupIDStr.$value;
        if($key!=count($groupViewID)-1)
            $groupIDStr=$groupIDStr.',';
    }       

    return $groupIDStr;
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is exactly what the PHP [implode()](http://www.php.net/implode) function is for.

Try

```
$groupIDStr = implode(',', $groupViewID);
```

Comment: Excellent.  Is there a variation that does `implode`, but start at `$groupViewID[3]` and go to the end?  Thanks!

Comment: What you need to do is create a new array which contains everything from `$groupViewID[3]` to the end, and provide that to implode. In the above example, you can just replace `$groupViewID` with `array_slice($groupViewID, 3)`.

Comment: Using PHP since the beginning. I still find parameter orders unnatural. I'd expect the subject first, like join [array] (with) [seperator], as the array is the most significant element in the operation.

Answer (score 9):

You want implode:

```
implode(',', $array);
```

https://www.php.net/implode

Answer (score 7):

[implode()](http://www.php.net/implode)

```
$a = array('a','b','c');
echo implode(",", $a); // a,b,c
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$arr = array('a','b','c');
$str = join(',',$arr);
```

join is an alias for implode, however I prefer it as it makes more sense to those from a Java or Perl background (and others).

Comment: Even though join is correct as well, I think most PHP developers are used to seeing implode instead. :)

Comment: @Carl Vondrick - all the more reason to use join() IMO, but I can understand that PHP developers would prefer to use implode(), as it *does* sound cooler.

Answer (score 1):

implode() function is the best way to do this. Additionally for the shake of related topic, you can use explode() function for making an array from a text like the following:

> $text = '18:09:00'; 
>   $t_array = explode(':', $text);

Answer (score 1):

You can use implode() even with empty delimeter: `implode(' ', $value);` pretty convenient.